Follow-up to Expected-Value Dice question
Problem: Given that the first 6 occurs before the first 5, what is the expected number of rolls of a fair six-sided dice it will take to roll a 6 for the first time and stop?
This question was asked here: Roll a fair 6−sided die until a 6 appears.Given that the first 6 occurs before the first 5, find the expected number of times the die was rolled
I, too, got the answer of 1.5 because I neglected the factor of 0.5 that we must divide by. However, I really thought that
$P($roll the first 6 on roll #N | first 6 occurs before first 5$)=\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{N-1}\frac{1}{6}$
The reason I thought so was because in order to determine this probability, I assumed that the first 5 would not occur before the first 6, and used the number $\frac{4}{6}$. How can one tell whether they are calculating the given probability or its numerator ($P(A\cap B)$)?

When you calculate the probability of A and B both occurring, $P(A ∩ B)$, you're looking at the ratio of the number of outcomes where they both occur, vs the total number of possible outcomes. Said another way, you're looking at the ratio of the areas of "outcome space": $$\frac{\text{Area where A and B overlap}}{\text{Total Area}}$$
When we condition a probability, we are only looking at the outcomes where the given condition occurs. The probability of event A given B is now the ratio of the number of outcomes where A and B both happen, vs the number of all outcomes where B happens. In other words, the denominator of our probability is the area where B happens, and the numerator is the portion of the area where B happens, where A also happens.
$$\frac{\text{Area where A and B overlap}}{\text{Area of B}}$$
Diagram of conditional probabilities
$P(\text{not A} ∩ B) = \frac{4}{6}$ because you are looking at the number of outcomes where not-A and B occur (the set {1,2,3,4}), out of the total number of outcomes ({1,2,3,4,5,6}).
$P(\text{not A} | B) = \frac{\frac{4}{6}}{1/2}$ because you are now looking at the the number of outcomes where not-A and B occur, out of the proportion of outcomes where B occurs, which is 1/2. (As Graham Kemp explained in his comment in the original question.)
Another way to realize that you're not looking at the correct conditional probabilities is to sum up all your probabilities:
$$\sum{P_i}=\left(\frac16\right)+\left(\frac16*\frac46\right)+\left(\frac16*\frac46*\frac46\right)+... = 1/2 \neq 1$$
and we know that probabilities have to sum to 1. So our probabilities are missing that factor of 2 to become legit probabilities.
P.S. I was very suspicious of the probability of needing 1 roll being 1/3. I ran a simulation, however, and it's true. When a 5 or a 6 can end the game, there's a 1/3 chance of the game ending on the first roll. Once you eliminate all the outcomes where 5 is the first roll, you still have 1/3 of the outcome space in that area which now only contains 6's. This is very similar to the Monty Hall problem, and why you should always switch doors.
